# Excel Not Responding when opening a new Workbook

Tags: ms-office, ventura, apple-silicon

I’ve been having an issue with Excel - whenever I’m working on a workbook and I try to open a new, blank file, Excel will beachball indefinitely until I force quit it. This happens no matter what the existing workbook I have open is - be it a multi-megabyte file or a 24kb list.

This happens whenever I want to open a new workbook - be it from the file menu, or when trying to move/copy a sheet to a new book. The only way I can create a new workbook without the app crashing is to open the app from the app icon, which will launch it with a new blank workbook.

I’ve uninstalled and reinstalled the app multiple times, both the App Store and web download versions, and cleared all preferences/plist files associated with it each time. At this point I have no idea what else to do.

I’m on a M2 Macbook Air running Ventura, and this is currently happening on excel 16.76 (but has been happening on previous versions as well.) To the best of my recollection this started happening last year when I bought the MBA - at first I though it was an issue with excel not being optimized for M series macs, but there’s been a few updates since then and I haven’t heard of this being a widespread error, so I think it has to be something on my end.

I’m attaching the error report to see if anyone can make any sense of this.

[MS Office Error Report](https://pastebin.com/x8rBukDn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just spent two days on a very similar issue and resolved it for myself.

This is how I fixed mine.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/255047298?answerId=259388014022&cid=em-com-apple_watches_email_thread_owner-view_the_full_discussion-en-us-11192020#259388014022

Tony

Comment: Amazing! This fixed it for me as well; I had changed the default font to Helvetica, and changing it back to Body Text solved the issue instantly. Thanks!!